# Porque cuando busco por nombre no encuentra el nombre dentro del ArrayList?

Tags: java, poo, arraylist

En un fiche ro almacenamos los datos de los clientes de una empresa con el formato nombre;localidad. El programa copiará ese datos en un ArrayList para que el usuario pueda elegir entre ver los datos de los clientes de una localidad  o  buscar entre los nombres.

```
    public class Repetir60 {
static ArrayList<String> datos = new ArrayList();
 public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    File f = new File("datos.dat");
    Scanner fichero = new Scanner(f);


    String linea;
    while (fichero.hasNext()) {
        linea = fichero.nextLine();

        datos.add(linea);

    }

    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("1 para buscar por nombre, 2 para buscar por localidad");
    int numero = teclado.nextInt();
    if (numero == 1) {
        buscarnombre( );

    }
    if (numero == 2) {
        buscarlocalidad();

    }

}

public static void buscarnombre( ) {
    String nombre;
    System.out.println("Escribe el nombre que quieres buscar");
    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
    nombre = teclado.nextLine();

    for (int i = 0; i < datos.size(); i++) {

        if (datos.get(i).equals(nombre)) {
            System.out.println(datos.get(i));

        }

    }
}

public static void buscarlocalidad( ) {

    String localidad;
    System.out.println("Escribe la localidad que quieres buscar");
    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
    localidad = teclado.nextLine();

}
```

}

Comment: Cúal es tu problema? porque ahí no tienes nada de código en el if que haces la comparación por nombre

Comment: if(datos.get(i).equals(nombre)) aqui hay algo que no funciona bien porque no me encuentra el nombre que escribo,pero no se que hago mal

Comment: Los datos del archivo si estan siendo cargados al ArrayList??

Comment: @HéctorHuertas estás *seguro* de que no lo encuentra? en tu código tienes `if(datos.get(i).equals(nombre)) {}` vacío. A lo mejor sí que lo encuentra pero no lo ves porque no haces nada en caso de entontrarlo.

Comment: Comprueba que en datos tienes realmente datos y lo que te comenta @DavidDPG y yo antes, si es porque no tienes código en el if

Comment: puse codigo dentro del if y aun sigue sin aparecer nada

Comment: es posible que datos esté vacío???

Comment: lo he comprobado sacandolo por pantalla y tiene los datos del fichero,no está vacio

Comment: Haz la comparación así: if(datos.get(i).trim().toUpperCase().equals(nombre.trim().toUpperCase())) así quitas espacios en blanco y comparas todo en mayúsculas

Comment: a mi no me deja introducirle el metodo trim() al ArrayList datos,no me sale despues de poner un "."

Comment: Lo que pasa es que en el metodo de buscarnombre() le estas pasando por argumentos el ArrayList, tienes que tomar el valor desde el de arriba que tienes creado desde el metodo main, deberias de crearla como variable de clase y no local, asi nunca podras acceder a sus datos.

Comment: @Dacoso he editado el codigo como me dijiste(o eso creo),asi deberia funcionar entonces?porque sigue sin entrarme en if(datos.get(i).equals(nombre))

Comment: No puedes hacer datos.get(i).trim() ??? asegúrate porque es un método de los strings. Al hacer datos.get(i) obtienes un String y debería de tener el método trim()

Comment: Me dejó ponerlo pero aun asi no entra en el if

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una buena solucion seria crear una clase cliente que almacene el nombre y la localidad asi:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Repetir60 {

    static ArrayList<Cliente> datos = new ArrayList();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        File f = new File("datos.dat");
        Scanner fichero = new Scanner(f);

        String linea;
        while (fichero.hasNext()) {
            linea = fichero.nextLine();
            String[] parts = linea.split(";");
            datos.add(new Cliente(parts[0], parts[1]));

        }

        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("1 para buscar por nombre, 2 para buscar por localidad");
        int numero = teclado.nextInt();
        if (numero == 1) {
            buscarnombre();

        }
        if (numero == 2) {
            buscarlocalidad();

        }

    }

    public static void buscarnombre() {
        String nombre;
        System.out.println("Escribe el nombre que quieres buscar");
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        nombre = teclado.nextLine();

        for (int i = 0; i < datos.size(); i++) {

            if (datos.get(i).getNombre().equalsIgnoreCase(nombre)) {
                System.out.println(datos.get(i));

            }
        }
    }

    public static void buscarlocalidad() {

        String localidad;
        System.out.println("Escribe la localidad que quieres buscar");
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        localidad = teclado.nextLine();

    }
}

class Cliente {

    String nombre;
    String localidad;

    public Cliente(String nombre, String localidad) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.localidad = localidad;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public String getLocalidad() {
        return localidad;
    }
}
```

Comment: Me ha servido de mucha ayuda,gracias!!

Answer (score 0):

Tu codigo esta buscando algo que esta mal..

No estas mostrando los datos de entrada, pero en la busqueda estas haciendo

```
datos.get(i).equals(nombre)
```

supongamos que ingresaste el nombre juan.. y en tu archivo dice:

juan;america

Por lo tanto, el `if(datos.get(i).equals(nombre))` va a dar falso siempre, porque juan no es igual a juan;america. Es mas, si buscaras america tenes el mismo problema.

Las posibles soluciones que tenes son:

- Separar el string de datos en dos array distintos, y buscar en el que
  corresponda.
- Crear una clase que contenga ambos datos y buscar donde corresponda
- Hacer una busqueda pero de un pedazo del string y no del completo.